# Running gulp.watch or gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

My project = coding website and I'm using gulp. 
Now, when running gulp v4 I'm using the cmd gulp watch which creates my site. 
But I would like to know what the cmd gulp is for then and when should I use gulp and when should I use gulp watch? 
I tried to use the cmd gulp but it gave me the error: Task never defined: default. 
I know I should run exports.default but I think I also need to create a function? 
Hope you can help me figure out if I need to use gulp or gulp watch and what to write for the exports.default. 
Here's my code :)

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');



// complie scss to css

function style() {
    //1. ehere is the scss file
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    //2. pass that file through sass compiler
        .pipe(sass().on('error', saas.logError))
    //3. where do I save the compled css?
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    //4. stream changes to all browsers 
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    //5. fixes scaling
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'));
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./*index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the gulp cmd you need to define the default export.

```
exports.default = watch
```

This is handy to define for a task that your using a lot.

Comment: And for instance `exports.default = gulp.series(style, watch);`  and then just command prompt `gulp` would run both of those functions for you.